# Passenger + Rails app only works on port 3000

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, passenger, ports

Passenger will start up on port 80, but only the home page (which is 100% HTML) shows up. No other page will resolve.  And even stranger, all traffic that fails to resolve is forwarded to HTTPS (which, of course, also fails to resolve).

This works:

```
rvmsudo passenger start --daemonize
```

This does not work:

```
rvmsudo passenger start --daemonize --port 80
```

My config.ru is pretty standard, too:

```
require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)
run Rails.application
```

I am using Rails 4.2.0 and Ruby 2.2.2 with Passenger 5.0.7

Anyone have any ideas?

nginx conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
    ##

    passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini
    #passenger_ruby /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2
```

app specific conf:

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.mydomain.com;

    # Tells Nginx to serve static assets from this directory.
    root /var/www/mydomain/public;

    location / {
        # Tells Nginx to forward all requests for www.foo.com
        # to the Passenger Standalone instance listening on port 4000.
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000;

        # These are "magic" Nginx configuration options that
        # should be present in order to make the reverse proxying
        # work properly. Also contains some options that make WebSockets
        # work properly with Passenger Standalone. Please learn more at
        # http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_buffering off;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that nothing else is running on port 80? Though it'd be weird I guess since passenger should have errored with a message letting you know it couldn't bind to port 80

Comment: Please add the OS to your question.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04.  Nothing else running on 80—I did a netstat and nothing else shows up.

Comment: You mean just HTML content of the page renders and not assets?

Comment: No, the home page is index.html, and that shows up fine.  Once another url is chosen by the user and Rails has to serve up the url, it fails.

Comment: Well, according to my routes, the home page is:   root_path GET / pages#index

Comment: Show me your server config file.

Comment: added nginx config info above

Comment: If I use thin instead of passenger, the same thing happens ( rvmsudo thin start -p 80 )

Comment: What about your redirection from your domain name? Did you do a `Type A` on DNS zone? Your bug might appear if you do only a simple redirection.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a different "setup"/configuration if you want to run passenger behind a nginx.

Nginx should listen on port 80 (its specified in the server-section of your nginx.conf), and forwards traffic to your app running under passengers hood (specified in nginx.conf to be on port 4000, but started by hand at port 80), if I do not misread.

Probably nginx tells you that its unhappy in its logfile /var/log/nginx.log I believe. You can confirm what is sitting on port 80 by executing `netstat -tlpn` .